# Setting "ifconfig-push [ip] 255.255.255.255" on clients config files

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN and I have encountered an issue that is bothering me a lot. When I put the netmask 255.255.255.255 to a client (setting a static ip with ifconfig-push), I am not able to access the gateway, which in my case is 10.8.0.1. This seems to function just as expected, because as the netmask the server assigns is 255.255.255.255, disabling any communtication from the client's IP (10.8.0.X) to any other client or the gateway. I have checked this not working on Linux and Windows. Nonetheless, on an Android device, it somehow seems to work, which bugs me and just doesn't make sense.

Comment: When you say "this not working on Linux and Windows," do you mean that you have network connectivity or that you do not have network connectivity?

Comment: In Linux, when openvpn runs "ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1", I get "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.", and it simply doesnt add a new route, so my internet works, but it just doesn't go through the VPN. On the other side, Windows forces those routes to apply, therefore, I am unable to access the Internet.
Additionally, I have discovered that if, in Linux, I delete the IP that openvpn has given me by doing "ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.50/32 broadcast 10.8.0.50" and then I added the same IP but changing the netmask "ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.50/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255".

Comment: This is the continuation of the previos message.
After that I tried "ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1" and "ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1" and the traffic was going through the VPN, alongside with any client-to-client connection. So I am guessing that OpenVPN on android does something similar, though I had installed a Terminal Emulator and "ip a" was telling me that the netmask in use was 255.255.255.255, and not 255.255.255.0 (which I had to set in Linux manully).

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question?  Linux performs sanity checking and doesn't allow an impossible route to be added.

Comment: Well, I guess that is right, though I still don't know how Android handles specified routes, nor why the same client.ovpn works on android without tinkering with the netmask but not on linux.
I guess this thread can be closed :)